# Collection Indexing Strategy

Tags: delphi, collections, indexing, tpersistent

I have a collection of TPersistent objects. I want to index them by their memory location (as main index) and by their properties (using rtti). A collection may have several property based indexes (based on different properties).

What is the strategy and data structure to solve this problem, so I can delete invalid objects (those that already been destroyed) from the collection without access violation when dealing with property based indexes?

Edit: to clarify things, I am hoping to implement this kind of interfaces (class and methods):

```
type
  TMyItem=class(TPersistent)
  public
    property HasProp[Name: string]: Boolean read GetHasProp;
    property PropValue[Name: string]: Variant read GetPropValue write SetPropValue;
  end;

  TMyCollection=class(TPersistent)
  private
    FMainList: TSortedList;
    FIndexes : TIndexes;
  public
    function Add(AItem: TMyItem): Integer;
    procedure Extract(AItem: TMyItem);
    procedure Delete(AItem: TMyItem);

    // and new sorted list based on the given property name to the FIndexes
    procedure AddIndex(const APropName: string);
    // remove sorted list correspoding to the given property name from FIndexes
    procedure RemoveIndex(const APropName: string);

    // just to see if the item is in the collection
    function Find(AItem: TMyItem): Boolean;
    // try to find first item which property specified by APropName has value specified by APropValue
    function Find(const APropName: string; const APropValue: Variant; var AItem: TMyItem): Boolean;
  end;
```

The FMainList contains list of pointers to TMyItem instances. Sorted by casting the pointers to NativeInt. So it will be no problem if I'am finding invalid objects. However in property based index, I am sorting TMyItems based on their property value. Therefore EAccessViolation will be raised if I am trying to find entry for invalid TMyItem (one that already been destroyed), since I need to fetch the property value.

My current idea to solve this is to store the position of a TMyItem in each property based index into main record that is stored in FMainList. But this approach also requires updating all positions each time new item is added or removed. This is what I want to avoid. So is there any other better mechanism?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question, but what do you mean by property based index? Do you mean the properties of the collection or that of the collection-items? And in case of the latter: properties like Name, Title, Age? What's the purpose of these multiple indexes?

Comment: @NGLN I mean by the properties of the collection items. The purpose is to quickly find the items when searching using their property. I want to have this kind of method in the collection: function Find(const APropName: string; const AValue: Variant; var AItem: TPersistent): Boolean;

Comment: @menjaraz: I am hoping that the solution should be run in any version of Delphi (32bit an later). And I couldn't see any possible problem with that.

Comment: @Menjaraz, let me worry about rtti things, let's focus on the strategy and data structure.

Comment: If I were you, I would choose a TCollection/TCollectionItem based implementation.

Answer (score 2):

These kind of questions generally lead to the choice between saving or calculating the index, which is synonymous to the choice between speed and memory. It also kind of depends on usage: are those `Find` routines called often?

Like you say yourself already: saving each index in a separate array brings all kind of synchronization issues with it, along with a significant extra need for memory.

Personally, I would calculate/get each index on request. Sure, it will *take some time* to iterate over all the items, but when the count stays, say, under 100K or even a higher number, I am sure it will not suffer from any delay. And when you base the design on `TCollection` like menjaraz comments, you do not have to worry about deleted items: there will be none.

#### Update:

Because you want to search for values in properties with arbitrary names for which the use of RTTI is needed, this iterative task may things slow down a bit. To eliminate that, I wrote this optimization for you. It is based on excluding the items in the search operation which do not have the property. For this I store the property names the collection contains in its items along with to which class they belong. The only limitation is that there can be no duplicate property names, but I suspect you will combine classes with the same property names in a common ancestor anyway. (It ís however possible to add classes with the same property names, as long as the second is inherited from the first.)

```
unit MyCollection;

interface

uses
  Classes, TypInfo;

type
  TMyItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  end;

  TMyCollection = class(TOwnedCollection)
  private
    FPrevItemClass: TClass;
    FPropList: TStringList;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyItem;
    procedure RegisterItemClass(AClass: TClass);
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TMyItem);
  protected
    procedure Notify(Item: TCollectionItem;
      Action: TCollectionNotification); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TPersistent); virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Find(AItem: TMyItem): Boolean; overload;
    function Find(const APropName: String; AValue: Variant;
      var AItem: TMyItem): Boolean; overload;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TMyItem read GetItem write SetItem;
      default;
  end;

implementation

resourcestring
  SDupPropName = 'Duplicate property name. Only classes with unique ' +
                 'property names are supposed to be added to this collection.';

{ TMyCollection }

constructor TMyCollection.Create(AOwner: TPersistent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner, TMyItem);
  FPropList := TStringList.Create;
  RegisterItemClass(TMyItem);
end;

destructor TMyCollection.Destroy;
begin
  FPropList.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TMyCollection.Find(AItem: TMyItem): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    if Items[I] = AItem then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  Result := False;
end;

function TMyCollection.Find(const APropName: String; AValue: Variant;
  var AItem: TMyItem): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  ItemClass: TClass;
begin
  Result := False;
  if FPropList.Find(APropName, I) then
  begin
    ItemClass := TClass(FPropList.Objects[I]);
    for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
      if Items[I] is ItemClass then
        if GetPropValue(Items[I], APropName, False) = AValue then
        begin
          AItem := Items[I];
          Result := True;
        end;
  end;
end;

function TMyCollection.GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyItem;
begin
  Result := TMyItem(inherited GetItem(Index));
end;

procedure TMyCollection.Notify(Item: TCollectionItem;
  Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  inherited Notify(Item, Action);
  if Action = cnAdded then
    if Item.ClassType <> FPrevItemClass then
      if FPropList.IndexOfObject(TObject(Item.ClassType)) = -1 then
        RegisterItemClass(Item.ClassType)
end;

procedure TMyCollection.RegisterItemClass(AClass: TClass);
var
  PropCount: Integer;
  PropList: PPropList;
  I: Integer;
  J: Integer;
  PropName: String;
begin
  PropCount := GetTypeData(AClass.ClassInfo)^.PropCount;
  if PropCount > 0 then
  try
    GetPropList(AClass.ClassInfo, PropList);
    for I := 0 to PropCount - 1 do
    begin
      PropName := PropList[I].Name;
      if not FPropList.Find(PropName, J) then
      begin
        FPropList.AddObject(PropName, TObject(AClass));
      end
      else
        if not AClass.InheritsFrom(TClass(FPropList.Objects[J])) then
          raise EInvalidOperation.Create(SDupPropName);
    end;
    FPrevItemClass := AClass;
  finally
    FreeMem(PropList);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyCollection.SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TMyItem);
begin
  inherited SetItem(Index, Value);
end;

end.
```

Comment: If the value to compare is flat (directly available) then yes, perhaps even in order of 100k members the penalty is still acceptable. But remember that I have to access the value through rtti which introduce more loads (each value reading involves several routine calls). That is why I need to sort it beforehand to reduce the finding load. Property based index is actually the most important factor in finding things in my case, since most query will be based on "primary key" and "unique key" (both are implemented as published property), and they may involve several properties.

Comment: @DonnVall Are you making data objects? And even if not, why not using 'fieldnames' instead of using rtti to retrieve property names?

Comment: In a sense yes, my objects could be considered data objects. However they are not only for holding data. They will have their own specific methods, behavior, and purposes. Do you mean "fieldnames" as in dataset? Well, I want my objects to behave like ordinary object instead of "record" (i.e. should be manipulated by others). The basics is similar with tiOPF.